# Implementation of Qserver and Qmux

Tags: iso8583, jpos

I'm learning about jpos. **I got jpos programmer's guide with me** and I have gone through that.
It helped me a lot in developing my switch.

I have some questions.

- Whether I created my switch Correctly?
- What are best practices for these situation:
- I have a switch get diffrent messages (two types of channel/packager) from one switch and response back to it (qserver and qmux or only qmux or ...)
- I have a switch get diffrent messages from diffrent banks and should reply them or forward messages to another (do I need qserver or just a qmux or need to have more configs on txmanager side)

now Im going to implement first situation In my switch flow is in this way:

Q2 will deploy by xml files:

- Server.xml
- RequestListener Class
- TransactionMangare.xml

Here, in QMUX, what I don't understand is:

Q2 will deploy by xml files

- (then I have QMUX.xml,Channeladaptor.xml and Listener Class [I want to know in what order it should come])
- TransactionMangare.xml

messages with diffrent channel would come to me through a single port. is it possible?
as Qmux would use key (Bit41 and mti) which needs to specify channel before giving to the right one (otherwise would get 41 wrong or it would not parse it at all)

here are my deploy files:

**logger.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <logger name="Q2Logger" class="org.jpos.q2.qbean.LoggerAdaptor">    
        <log-listener class="org.jpos.util.SimpleLogListener" /> 
    </logger>
```

**server.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <server class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer" logger="Q2Logger" name="TransactionServer"> 
           <attr name="port" type="java.lang.Integer">88800</attr>  
        <attr name="maxSessions" type="java.lang.Integer">20</attr>     
        <attr name="minSessions" type="java.lang.Integer">10</attr>     
    
        <!-- packager is customised (I also need another packager for another type of messages) --> 
        <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel" name="ASCIIChannel" logger="Q2Logger"             packager="com.example.transaction.packager.ISO93APackager" header="ISO51300000">       
            <property name="timeout" value="70000" /> <!-- 7 minutes -->        
            <property name="keep-alive" value="true" />     
        </channel> 
    
        <!-- can have realm="incoming-request-listener" -> to automatically put into space ???? -->     
        <request-listener class="com.example.transaction.listener.ServerRequestListener" logger="Q2Logger" name="isoListener">      
            <property name="space" value="transient:default" />         
            <property name="queue" value="CerditCardTXNQueue" />        
            <property name="spaceTimeout" value="60000" />  
         </request-listener> 
    </server>
```

**txnmgr.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <txnmgr name="CreditCardTransactionManager" logger="Q2Logger" class="org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager">  
        <property name="space" value="transient:default" />     
        <property name="queue" value="TXNQueue" />  
        <property name="sessions" value="5" />  
        <property name="debug" value="true" />  
    
        <participant class="com.example.transaction.participants.PrepareParticipant" logger="Q2Logger" />   
        <participant class="com.example.transaction.participants.ValidationParticipant" logger="Q2Logger" />    
        <participant class="com.example.transaction.participants.ProcessParticipant" logger="Q2Logger" />   
        <participant class="com.example.transaction.participants.SendResponseParticipant" logger="Q2Logger"/> 
    </txnmgr>
```

Thanks,